# GWT - Netbeans cant start dev mode

Tags: java, gwt, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I have netbeans with the GWT4NB plugin installed. My code can compile and works with production mode. But when I try to launch the dev mode aka hosted mode in Netbeans the GWTShell window doesn't load. Getting this to work would be greatly useful for debugging. Here is my error in the console:

```
GWT4NB https://gwt4nb.dev.java.net
GWT installation directory: C:\Users\Guillaume\.netbeans\6.9\framework\gwt-2.1.0
init:
debug-connect-gwt-shell-hosted-15:
Unknown argument: -style
Google Web Toolkit 2.1.0
GWTShell [-noserver] [-port port-number | "auto"] [-whitelist whitelist-string] [-blacklist blacklist-string] [-logdir directory] [-logLevel level] [-gen dir] [-bindAddress host-name-or-address] [-codeServerPort port-number | "auto"] [-out dir] [url]

where 
  -noserver        Prevents the embedded web server from running
  -port            Specifies the TCP port for the embedded web server (defaults to 8888)
  -whitelist       Allows the user to browse URLs that match the specified regexes (comma or space separated)
  -blacklist       Prevents the user browsing URLs that match the specified regexes (comma or space separated)
  -logdir          Logs to a file in the given directory, as well as graphically
  -logLevel        The level of logging detail: ERROR, WARN, INFO, TRACE, DEBUG, SPAM, or ALL
  -gen             Debugging: causes normally-transient generated types to be saved in the specified directory
  -bindAddress     Specifies the bind address for the code server and web server (defaults to 127.0.0.1)
  -codeServerPort  Specifies the TCP port for the code server (defaults to 9997)
  -out             The directory to write output files into (defaults to current)
and 
  url              Automatically launches the specified URL
Java Result: -1
init:
```

The problem seems to be the unknown -style argument. I tried changing this argument in build-gwt.xml under the gwt 2.0 section, no changes. Why isnt gwt 2.1 not in the xml config file also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue and fix it manually on every restart by setting the gwt version as '2.0' even if I am actually on 2.2.

The problem is caused by the fact that the GWT4NB does not undertand the version of GWT you are using and so tries with GWT 1.5, that is pretty different from modern ones.

Comment: I switched gwt.version=2.1 to gwt.version=2.0 in the gwt.properties file. Not sure If I had this changed to 2.1 myself, but now it works with 2.0 has setting.

Comment: Works for me, thanks!  NOTE: Projects -> right-click on GWT-project -> Properties -> Google Web Toolkit -> GWT Version -> Change to 2.0 (or whatever version you are using; 2.0 is as high as the plugin goes at the moment)